# Is there a way to make $ and & have different colors in the TeXShop editor?

Tags: texshop, syntax-highlighting

I'm using a lot of equations in a tabular environment, and it's hard to tell apart the $ math mode symbols from the & alignment symbols because they're both orange. In TeXShop -> Preferences -> Themes there's only the option to change marker color, which affects both $ and &. Is there a way to color them separately, for example leave $ as orange and change & to purple?

[image]

Comment: I don't know about texshop but you should use `array` not `tabular` then all the entries are in math and you do not need `$` (that is the only difference between `array` and `tabular` they share the same implementation)